# discord on_message fixing python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

On my function `async for msg in ctx.channel.history(limit=1):` in the on_message event I get this error:

````
discord.errors.HTTPException: 524  (error code: 0): <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->```

And then it shows a loooonng html code...
````

Comment: There is no `context` in the `on_message` event.

Comment: ^ use `message.channel.history`. If that doesn't work can you add the full traceback for it?

Comment: where is the code of your `on_message`? We can't read in your mind. You have to show all details in question.

Answer (score 0):

The 524 error is a server timeout error. This means that there is a problem with your computer (or host) and discord.

To fix this, try:

- restarting your computer
- clearing the DNS cache
- running your bot on a virtual environment

If none of these work try going to https://discord.com and seeing if it'll connect.